# Walking a hierarchical tree

Tags: r, matrix, hierarchy

I want to be able to "walk" (iterate) through a hierarchical cluster (see figure below and code). What I want is:

1. A function that that takes a matrix and a minimum height. Say 10 in this example.

   ```
   splitme <- function(matrix, minH){
       ##Some code
   }
   ```
2. Starting from the top to `minH`, start cutting whenever there is a new split. This is the first problem. How to detect a new splits to get an height `h`.
3. At this particular `h`, how many clusters are there? Retrieve clusters

   ```
   mycl <- cutree(hr, h=x);#x is that found h
   count <- count(mycl)# Bad code
   ```
4. Save in variable(s) each of the new matrices. This is another hard one, dynamic creation of x new matrices. So perhaps a function that takes the clusters does what needs to be done (comparisons) and returns a variable ??
5. Continue 3 and 4 until `minH` reached

#### Figure

[image]

#### Code

```
# Generate data
set.seed(12345)
desc.1 <- c(rnorm(10, 0, 1), rnorm(20, 10, 4))
desc.2 <- c(rnorm(5, 20, .5), rnorm(5, 5, 1.5), rnorm(20, 10, 2))
desc.3 <- c(rnorm(10, 3, .1), rnorm(15, 6, .2), rnorm(5, 5, .3))

data <- cbind(desc.1, desc.2, desc.3)

# Create dendrogram
d <- dist(data) 
hc <- as.dendrogram(hclust(d))

# Function to color branches
colbranches <- function(n, col)
  {
  a <- attributes(n) # Find the attributes of current node
  # Color edges with requested color
  attr(n, "edgePar") <- c(a$edgePar, list(col=col, lwd=2))
  n # Don't forget to return the node!
  }

# Color the first sub-branch of the first branch in red,
# the second sub-branch in orange and the second branch in blue
hc[[1]][[1]] = dendrapply(hc[[1]][[1]], colbranches, "red")
hc[[1]][[2]] = dendrapply(hc[[1]][[2]], colbranches, "orange")
hc[[2]] = dendrapply(hc[[2]], colbranches, "blue")

# Plot
plot(hc)
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Ad 1) do you speak about a matrix or a tree? What matrix do you mean? Can you possibly illustrate by picture what you want? Ad 3) what do you mean by clusters? 4) what matrices you speak about?? PLease edit the question to be more comprehensible (but not much longer) so that we know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Think of it this way, every time you see a split in the figure, that is creating a split in the data where there was once 1 matrix now there will be two. Each split is determined by the cluster.

Comment: Well, I asked you to explain the terms, you don't explain them and keep juggling with them. Do you think this will make the question more clear?

Comment: Well, i think it is clear. There is dataset (matrix here), which i do hierarchical clustering to make a tree (again all in the code provided), now I want to start at the top of the tree (see fig), the first split is blue vs gray. I want it to give me two sub matrices of what constitutes the blue stuff as a matrix, and another for gray (red and yellow). Then keep doing the same thing. the next split is say between red and yellow in the grey branch. So another 2 matrices there.

Comment: dendroapply() is a very powerful function to traverse the dendrogram, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need essentially is the cophenetic correlation coefficient of the dendrogram.
It will tell you the heights of all splitting points. From there you can easily walk through the tree.
I made an attempt below and store all submatrices to a list "submatrices". It's a nested list. The first level is the submatrices from all splitting points. The second level is the submatrices from a splitting point.
For example, if you want all submatrices from the 1st splitting point (grey and blue clusters), it should be submatrices[[1]]. If you want the first submatrix (red cluster) from submatrices[[1]], it should be submatrices[[1]][1].

```
splitme <- function(data, minH){
  ##Compute dist matrix and clustering dendrogram
  d <- dist(data)
  cl <- hclust(d)
  hc <- as.dendrogram(cl)

  ##Get the cophenetic correlation coefficient matrix (cccm)
  cccm <- round(cophenetic(hc), digits = 0)

  #Get the heights of spliting points (sps)
  sps <- sort(unique(cccm), decreasing = T)

  #This list store all the submatrices
  #The submatrices extract from the nth splitting points
  #(top splitting point being the 1st whereas bottom splitting point being the last)
  submatrices <- list()

  #Iterate/Walk the dendrogram
  i <- 2 #Starting from 2 as the 1st value will give you the entire dendrogram as a whole
  while(sps[i] > minH){
    membership <- cutree(cl, h=sps[i]) #Cut the tree at splitting points
    lst <- list() #Create a list to store submatrices extract from a splitting point
    for(j in 1:max(membership)){
      member <- which(membership == j) #Get the corresponding data entry to create the submatrices
      df <- data.frame()
      for(p in member){
        df <- rbind(df, data[p, ])
        colnames(df) <- colnames(data)
        dm <- dist(df)
      }
      lst <- append(lst, list(dm)) #Append all submatrices from a splitting point to lst
    }
    submatrices <- append(submatrices, list(lst)) #Append the lst to submatrices list
    i <- i + 1
  }
  return(submatrices)
}
```

Comment: This works, but having to manipulate it for my specific example. Still working on it. i will comment more if I hit a wall. Thx

Comment: Is there an easy way that it will show you how many sub, and sub sub, ... matrices it has? because it is hard to guess in a large and not so obvious tree where you are.

Comment: Well, I just realized I forgot to add the return statement to the splitme function (I just edit my post to fix that). Now, if you want to know how many sub and sub-sub matrices there are, you can simply do: all_matrices <- splitme(data, 5) and then: lapply(all_matrices, length)